# Tao gesture method not triggered

Tags: ios, ios7, gesture

i am trying to add gesture programmatically but messagesBucketTap method not print log

```
// 
control=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ControlScene"];
control.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,control.view.frame.size.width,60);
[self.view addSubview:control.view];
//
UITapGestureRecognizer *messagesTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(messagesBucketTap:)];
[messagesTap setDelegate:self];
[messagesTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[messagesTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];
[control.view addGestureRecognizer:messagesTap];

- (void)messagesBucketTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
NSLog(@"ramy'");}
```

Comment: I thought that was Terrence Tao... Your code looks fine. Have you checked to make sure that the view is positioned correct (try changing its background color). Also you don't need `setDelegate` here. And are you sure you want user to tap with *2 fingers* (`numberOfTouches = 2`)??

Comment: Assuming you do really want the tap to require two fingers, make sure both fingers are touching `control.view`. If one finger touches the view and the other finger touches outside the view, it won't register.

Comment: yeah and 60px height is pretty tough for 2 fingers

Comment: @KhanhNguyen yeah you was right , my view has to uiview one 6opx height and the other was on middle of parent view , so didn`t accept any touch ,Thanks